# Search key in multidimensional array with 2 parameters

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array and I would like to search with 2 parameters : city and zip.

My array :

```
$result=array(2) { 
          [0]=> array(2) 
              { 
                  ["city"]=> string(9) "Paris" 
                  ["zip"]=> string(5) "75000" 
              } 
          [1]=> array(2) 
              {
                  ["city"]=> string(9) "Paris"
                  ["zip"]=> string(5) "75100" 
              }
          }
```

Ex : search the key value for city=paris and zip=75100

Key=1

An idea ?

Comment: qUESTION IS UNCLEAR? WHAT YOU WILL PASS? KEY OR  `city and zip.`? IF SECOND THEN  OUTPUT WILL BE `city=paris and zip=75000 `  NOT `75100`?

Comment: Yes : 75000 and Paris Key=0 / 75100 and Paris Key=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function..

```
function find_key($city, $zip) {

    foreach($result as $key => $value) {
        if($value['city'] == $city && $value['zip'] == $zip) {
             return $key;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}

$key = find_key('paris','75100');
if($key) {
    echo 'Found at key:'.$key;
} else {
    echo 'Not Found';
}
```

Comment: Hello, I think the best it will putt an extra field with the array on the function($city,$zip,$result) and call on $key=find_key('paris', '750100',$result)

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
<?php

$result=array(
          array( "city"=> "Paris", "zip"=>"75000"),
          array( "city"=> "Paris", "zip"=>"75100")
    );



$searchCity = "Paris";
$searchZip = "75100";


foreach($result as $key=>$row){
    if($row['city'] == $searchCity && $row['zip'] == $searchZip){
        echo $key;
    }
}

?>
```